# How to create an flying island out of 2 landscapes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

So yeah, this is a very specific question.
I wanted to make a flying island (defiently not inspired by CG Geek)
But when I have the landscapes, one for the top and one for the bottom, I cant make them look good together. They are angular, which doesnt look like an island. I tried fixing that with a ring and knife project and then merging, but that absolutely did go wrong
[image]

SO what would be the best way to merge these to landscapes together, and so they are not angular?

Comment: Have you tried a Boolean modifier (Union)? Then you can remesh and make it rounder in Sculpt mode

Comment: I mean, it kiiinda works, but then the edges of the island are very thin, trying to fix it with sculpting completely destroys the geometry, any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step to create an island from the two planes is to select and join both objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) in *Object* mode.

Then check the normals with the *Face Orientation* overlay. The normals of the upper part should point upwards (blue), and the normals of the bottom part downwards (blue). That is, all faces outside should be blue and everything inside should be red. That's important for the Boolean modifier to work properly.

If it looks wrong, you can flip the normals in *Edit* mode. Hover the mouse pointer over the mesh and select everything with <kbd>L</kbd> (*Select Linked*), then flip the normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, *Flip*.

[image: joined island with correct face orientation]
<sup>Joined island with correct face orientation</sup>

Now add a new cylinder (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Mesh > Cylinder*) object, in the *Adjust Last Operation* popup that appears (<kbd>F9</kbd> if you missed it) increase the number of vertices from default 32 to `96` to give it more geometry.

Move the cylinder to the island and add a *Boolean* modifier to the island. Choose `Intersect`, and *Solver* set to `Exact`. Hide the cylinder and disable it for rendering or apply the modifier and delete the cylinder.

[image: round island]

For sculpting, you can use the *Remesh* button (or apply *Remesh* modifier with operation type *Voxel*). This will create a mesh with even distributed vertices. Beware, the voxel size depends on your object size. Save before you do remesh operation because a too small number can freeze Blender and generate millions of vertices. I've used `0.05 m` for 2-3 m objects.

Of course, you can also create a square or other shaped island in this way.

Comment: It works really good, thank you for the detailed answer, I absolutely appreciate it. Just one thing, what would be the best sculpt tool or the best way to get rid of the thin rim of the island?

Comment: Oh, I thought you want to have the rim so thin? You can pull the top and bottom of the island apart to make the edge thicker or make the cylinder smaller. Of course, you can use *Inflate* brush to make it thicker. Other useful brushes are *Grab, Elastic Deform, Snakehook* and *Smooth* brush. Use a lower strength (0.1-0.2) for the Smooth brush to smooth the surface & a higher strength (0.5+) to "melt away" unwanted volume. To add "rocks" you can define a vertex group in *Edit* mode, and use it with a *Displace* modifier. Direction can be set to Z-axis to limit deformation only to the height.

Comment: Ok I got it, it works perfectly, thanks a lot for the help